# JavaScript Symbols are not stopping name clashes in Objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, symbols

I have started to take a look at Symbols in JavaScript, and have started to use them in my Objects to help with name clashes, but I can still overwrite properties when using them? I'm having a really hard time to understand what the point of Symbols are in JavaScript. They are spoken about a lot and people say they are brilliant because they don't cause naming conflicts in Objects, but I can't see how?

```js
    // Create your object
let obj = {};

// Create your Symbol
let address = Symbol("the address symbol");

// Assign your Symbol as a key to a value
obj[address] = "123 Bond street";

// Return '123 Bond street'
console.log(obj[address])


// Another dev comes along

// Assigns an address property to your object
obj[address] = "456 Regent street";

// Your address property has been overwritten?
console.log(obj[address])
```

As far as I can see from my code I can still overwrite properties on the Object? So how did the Symbol help?

Am I using them wrong?

Comment: Of course you are overwriting the property. The Symbol you've created is being stored in `address` and then you set that key twice. Your code simply generates a dynamic unique symbol and then stores it statically.

Comment: it would stop `obj.address = "456 Regent street";`

Comment: @dandavis Of course it would since `address` was never the key name in the first place.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: right, so if you control access to that local, you control access to the prop...

Comment: You would need to create a second Symbol: `const address2 = Symbol("the address symbol");`. If your code actually avoided name clashes, how would you ever be able to _update_ a property stored with a Symbol key?

Answer (score 5):

It appears that you are under the impression that every time you access `address` a new and different Symbol value will be assigned, which is not correct.

All you are doing is using Symbol to generate a unique value and then you are storing that value in the `address` variable. That means that when you use it again later, you are using the same Symbol you generated earlier. This would be the case even if you weren't using Symbol:

```js
let obj = {};   // Create your object
    
let address = "some key name";
obj[address] = "123 Bond street";  
console.log(obj[address]);  // Return '123 Bond street'
    
// Another dev comes along
obj[address] = "456 Regent street";   // Assigns an address property to your object
console.log(obj[address]);  // Your address property has been overwritten
```

In short, if you store a Symbol, you've done nothing more than stored a value that's guaranteed to be unique. But, that doesn't stop you from using it over and over.

A more appropriate use for `Symbol` would be to prevent another developer from creating a ***new*** key on an existing object with the same name as keys that were made from other Symbols:

```js
let obj = {};   // Create your object
    
let address = Symbol("some key name");
obj[address] = "123 Bond street";  
console.log(obj[address]);  // Return '123 Bond street'
    
// Another dev comes along
let newProp = Symbol("some key name");
obj[newProp] = "456 Regent street";   // Guaranteed unique new key is created

// There is no way the two properties would ever overwrite each other because each
// was created from a different Symbol
console.log(obj[address]);  
console.log(obj[newProp]);
```

Comment: Hi @ScottMarcus, would it be possible to also show your last example using Strings for comparison  instead of Symbols, and explain how the String keys could then be overwritten as I can't quote understand, (I have written out the code using Strings, but the result is the same and I can't get my head around a situation where it would be possible to overwrite the property, I mean I know if someone tries to create an existing String variable property it will overwrite the existing one, but the same goes if they create another Symbol and assign it to the original variable).   Thanks.

Comment: @Zippy I'm not sure I follow. The example above would be just about the same when not using Symbols, just remove `new Symbol("some key name")` and replace it with `"some key name"`. The issue would then be that someone could use the same key name that has already been used and therefore overwrite what's in the key.

Comment: @ScorrMarcus, thanks for the reply.  What I mean is, every example I've seen, shows someone else coming along and trying to create a property of an object, say 'age' where that property already exists. If we then access 'age', it will then return the new value (which is expected), however they then show a similar example using symbols, but when the attempt to create a new property (where one exists), they always show them using a different variable name, which clearly isn't going to overwrite the original.  Apologies if it's still not clear.  I'm just having trouble work it all out! Thanks.

Comment: That's exactly what my last example shows. The first property name is generated from a symbol and stored in the `address` variable and the second property name is a different value generated from a different Symbol and stored in the `newProp` variable.