# JavaScript Symbols not working as intended inside objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, symbols

**I have started to take a look at Symbols in JavaScript, and have started to use them in my Objects to help with name clashes, but I can still overwrite properties when using them?**

**// First developer code**

```
let id = Symbol('id');
let user = {
name: 'Karan',
[id]: 25,
}
```

**Now I have cloned their code and using it**

I can still do , `user[id] = 45 // This will turn the id value to 45`

This is as same as if using normal string 'id' in place of symbol

(First developer code )

```
let user = {
name: 'Karan',
'id' : 25,
}
```

Now I have cloned their code or say other developer does

`user.id = 28;`

Value of id is changed

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Can you put a [mcve] in a snippet in the question?  That would help convey what exactly the issue you are facing.  Include the expected behavior and the actual behavior as well.

Comment: "*I can still do `user[id] = 45`*" - only if `id` is a global variable that you can access.

Comment: You have to keep the value of your symbol variable `id` private (not available to outside code) for this to have any utility.  And, even then, one can still get access to it with `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols()`.  Plus `user.id = 28` is assigning to a new and different property with the property name of `"id"` which has nothing to do with `user[id]`.  That's a different property than your symbol.

Comment: @Olian04 This is what I am asking : Kinldy help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50806000/javascript-symbols-are-not-stopping-name-clashes-in-objects

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that you keep the Symbol instance private. It won't magically stop you from overwriting properties.

One section of your code can create the symbol:

```
let id = Symbol("id");
```

They can then use this symbol as a property on an object:`

```
let user = {
  [id]: 123,
};
```

However, another section of your code will not be able to overwrite the properties **if they do not have access to the same symbol instance**.

For example, if another piece of code creates their own symbol, the property they retrieve will be `undefined`:

```
let id2 = Symbol("id");
console.log(user[id2]); // undefined
```

It is up to you to isolate this symbol instance from the rest of the code.

The modern way to do this would be to put it in an ESM module and to not `export` the variable.

In your case, it looks like `id` is a global variable. This will not help you because you cannot guarantee no-one will use this variable.

Comment: Can you please look at this question, because this is exactly where I'm suffering. 
Link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50806000/javascript-symbols-are-not-stopping-name-clashes-in-objects

Comment: @Thelostcause My answer should suffice. You must isolate the symbol instance `id` from the rest of your code, by putting it in its own code block / scope, inside it's own ESM module, etc.